# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

To prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ does not unif. converge on $(-1,1)$, let $f_n$ be the partial sum, can I use the difference $|\frac{1}{1-x} - f_n|$ diverges?

Comment: Yes, you can (and should).

Answer (score 1):

We have $|\frac{1}{1-x}-\sum_{n=0}^N x^n|= \frac{|x|^{N+1}}{1-x} \to \infty$ for $x \to 1$. This shows that $(\sum_{n=0}^N x^n)_N$ does not converge uniformly to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ on $(-1,1)$.